# What is the first filed country of patent CN 101361713 B?

Tags: espacenet, cn101361713b, cn101361713a

*Curcumin nano crystallization preparation and preparation method thereof*

[CN 101361713 B](http://www.google.com/patents/CN101361713B)

Which is the first filing country with state?

Answer (score 0):

There are only two documents in this patent family, the application and grant in China. No other applications were filed in other countries.

Answer (score 0):

The first filing country is China.

The two documents refer to the 18 months Chinese publication which has the A kind code, and the grant (in China), with the B kind code.